# Codeigniter passing two values on callback (form_validation)

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm trying to pass two values to a function, so that i can check the username and password for the users. However, i can't get it to work. When i have one value, there is ne problem doing this. But how can i pass more than one value?

`function($val1, $val2)`

This is my code
http://pastebin.com/JKnTEqLN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass two variables to your function, change line 6

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|alpha|xss_clean|callback__check_login');
```

to

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|alpha|xss_clean|callback__check_login[$val1,$val2]');
```

For more than two values, youll need to use `http_build_query($val2)` and then `explode` it inside of your function

Answer (score 1):

(please correct me if I didn't get the question right:)

I wouldn't do that way.

Instead of using the _check_login() function callback as a validator for the username field (which doesn't really make sense, imho), why not call the `check_login($username,$password)` function WHEN the input fields are validated?

So

```
  if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
   $this->load->view('user_login');
  }
  else
  {
    $this->user_model->check_login();
  }
```

In User model you will be doing the check

Anyway, that's what the form_validation library is for, to validate inputs, not to elaborate datas.

If you just wanna check the existence of a user (to avoid duplicates, for example) to validate the input field, then you don't need the $password parameter, so the callback would work just fine.

Comment: well, if i do it that way, i don't get any error messages from the validation_errors() do i? so, thats a bit weird i think..

Comment: hm, did it another way around. So, thanks for the handsup anyway m8.

Answer (score 0):

public function score_check($name, $arr)
    {If you would like to pass two variables I have found the best way to create an array with both variables.

```
$arr = array($val1, $val2);
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|alpha|xss_clean|callback__check_login['.$arr.']');
```

Your callback would be something like

```
public function check_login($str, $arr) {
      $val1  = $arr[0];
      $val2 = $arr[1];
}
```

Hope that helps